# Docker will not run docker run -p 6379:6379 –name some-redis -d redis command

Tags: javascript, docker, redis, docker-run

For my course we have to run:
docker run -p 6379:6379 –name some-redis -d redis:4.0.1

But when I run this command it says that its on invalid format. This class is a couple years old so I know things change but in the project instructions it said to use this instead of what the video showed and it seems to be working for the rest of my class mates so I am kind of at a lost on how to move forward without getting this container.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've copied it wrong, but it's not `–name` but `--name`. Apart from that, I have no format error on my end.

Comment: I wish I did but I pasted it and noticed that as well when I ran docker run --help that -name was --name and -d was not a command but I am unsure of what they meant

Comment: `-d` is the shortened form of `--detach` which runs the container independently from the command line. From the docs: `Run container in background and print container ID`